# Does char* cause memory leak if passed to a function

Tags: c, string

I have a function like this:

```
void readString(char* str){
  str="asd";
}
```

Can I know if `str` will be dealloced? Or must I free it?

Note: I can't use string library as I am programming a microprocessor.

Comment: @Corbin, turn of the Sheldon Cooper mode, we all know what the OP really asked.

Comment: @user1764961 Because assumptions in the world of C always end very well :)

Comment: @Corbin isn't `str` a local variable? Calling this function should have no effect.

Comment: @juanchopanza Wow. I just went full-stupid for a second. Very good point! Not sure why I read this as char** x.x

Comment: @juanchopanza, ....... That probably would have been important with my  comment :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`free()` must only be called if `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()` was used to allocate memory. This is not the case in the posted code so calling `free()` is unrequired.

The `"asd"` is a string literal and exists for the lifetime of the program (has static storage duration).

Answer (score 3):

Your function does nothing.

It doesn't "read" a string. All it does it assign the address of a string literal (a constant block of memory somewhere that is initialized to the text of the string) to the function's local variable `str`.  The function then exits, causing that local variable to stop existing.

Nothing is returned, and the pointer is not de-referenced (which would in turn be wrong since it's only a `char *`, not a `char * *`), so nothing happens outside the function. The caller doesn't "get" any value, and thus has nothing to call `free()` on, so that problem can never even occur.

Answer (score 2):

String will not be deallocated because it is stored in static memory. You didn't allocate it, you don't free it

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no memory leak. In your case it is statically allocated.

Answer (score 0):

In general you have to make up your own rules about who can or must free memory, and you should document your code so it is clear what the requirements are.

In the example given,  `readString()` only overwrites its own private copy of the pointer, and when it returns the caller will not see that anything has changed.  Consequently the caller will have the same duty to `free()` its pointer as it had before it called `readString()`, and there will be no leak.

However, if `readString()` instead accepted a `char **`, so that it could modify the caller's copy of the pointer, then the outcome would be that it would not be legal to call `free()` after calling `readString()`, as the pointer's new value is not part of the malloc heap.

If the previous value of that pointer variable had been a `malloc()`ed object, then the caller should have freed it before allowing the pointer to be overwritten.  It would be truly horrible to have `readString()` call `free()` in that case, because it would turn a variable which must eventually be freed into one which must never be freed, and the program flow would be very hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

This code is useless and meaningless as for as I am concerned. Here are different ways of calling your function definition and why I say this!

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    char a, *b, *c;

    b = malloc (10);

    readString(&a); // Case-1, Valid calling.
    readString(b); // Case-2, Valid calling.
    readString(c); // Case-3, Invalid calling. Unallocated location.
}
```

Case-1: This is the only case, where it matters to the caller about what you do in your function. You may use the passed character as you wish. The only meaningful assignment would be something like this. Doing 'str = "asd";' would probably dump the core or mess with the caller's stack or data segment memory(if address of a global variable was passed) and create a complicated debugging nightmare!

```
void readString(char* str){
    *str='a';
}
```

Case-2: There is nothing Fatal or Syntax error in the code, but it is meaningless to do this. The only meaningful thing would be, just using what ever passed to your function from the caller. What is the reason for assigning like this on the passed parameter? Your definition can just have a local variable and avoid parameter passing completely. That function can be called as "readString();"...

```
void readString(void){
    char *str='asd';
}
```